# select a record from a list-box using text in Protractor

Tags: automation, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I want to select the record from the list box using text. how can i use the filter function to select the particular record.  I will be having many options but i want to select the value which i want by checking the text (e.g Spanish). I dont want to select value by index becoz if i do that i wont be able to verify test, moreover list gets updated. kindly help. below r my html code.

```
 <ul class="addList">
    <li ng-repeat="skill in availableSkills" ng-click="addSkillFunc(skill, $index)" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Mandarin</li>
<li ng-repeat="skill in availableSkills" ng-click="addSkillFunc(skill, $index)" class="ng-binding ng-scope">English</li>
<li ng-repeat="skill in availableSkills" ng-click="addSkillFunc(skill, $index)" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Spanish</li>
</ul>
```

Yea i can select the record by index. but i want something like selectbyvisibleText which is available in Selenium.

Comment: Have you tried using `getText()` function to get the text of the list option and then return the one that matches? Thanks

Comment: no @GirishSortur can u explain how to do that. How can i getText of all the options and return the match value.

Comment: Any updates please @GirishSortur

Comment: doesn't alecxe's answer help? Thanks

Comment: i thought the way u suggested looks good so that i was waiting for ur explanation. @GirishSortur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the solution. created a function SelectRowByCellValue and used to call it where ever i want by

```
SelectRowByCellValue(AGP.SkillList, Data.SkillSelect);
```

SkillList = element.all(by.css('Ul.addList li'));
SkillSelect = Value that u want to select. (Spanish)

```
this.SelectRowByCellValue = function (Elem, Texts) {

 Elem.filter(function (element) {
 return element.getText().then(function (text) {
 if (text == Texts) {
 element.click();
 return false;
 }
   });
}).then(function (filteredElements) {

 });
};
```